# Fragment transaction does not hide flash player

Tags: android, flash, fragment

I have two fragments.

In the first one I have a webview.

In the second I have another webview.

I have added these fragments to the Actionbar as tabs.

In the first fragment webview, when I have opened some flash videos, all was good, but then disaster- I opened the second fragment, but from the first fragment the flash player was still visible.

In this [link](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=167870203365173&set=a.167870216698505.1073741825.100004265825868&type=1&theater) is croped picture
Behind flash player google.com  is opened in fragment two.

How can I fix it. I'm changing fragments with a simple TabListener `ft.show()`; and `ft.hide();`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this happens because WebView use a surface as for playing video. The problem is that `SurfaceView` lock window space.

I think in your case `ft.replace()` would be preferable for tab change and should fix this problem. Also you could try to leave show/hide transaction type and "kill" your `WebView` somehow (maybe even by `wv = null;`) in `onPause()` or `onStop()` callbacks and restore it in `onStart()`.

Good luck!

Comment: Is it posible somehow getSurfaceView from WebView and hide it?

Comment: I've done, for webview need setOnHierarchyChangeListener there set surfaceView.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(isHidden());

Comment: Can you please explain how you solved it? I have the same issue.